# Grouping cells with at least some value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to fill column N with a value say 'Yes' or 'No' based on the values from Column N to Column Z. It should return Yes if there's atleast one value from N  to Z.

Alternatively, if I could just filter out the rows that don't have any values from column N-Z.

Is there a way to do this? Screenshot of the same excel sheet is attached for reference.

[image]

Comment: What happens when column N already has value  ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant you trying to populate column `M` instead of `N` (according to your printscreen. You can simply use `=COUNTBLANK` function to count the empty cells in a range.

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(N2:Z2)=13,"No","Yes")
```

Filter column `M` after you apply the formula to your range.

Comment: Tried this and worked like a charm. Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 1):

Reference: CountA function count non empty cells.

Try:

```
=IF(COUNTA(N2:Z2)=0,"No","Yes")
```